# OpenGL- glDrawElements only draws first element

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

Hi everyone i'm making a little 3d engine for my games and i created a class for vertex arrays and VBO. It was working until i tried to add indexing to the vertex array. Now it only draws the first element indexed!

Here is the function build, that generates the VAO and the VBOs.

```
void build() {
vboID = new GLuint[vboS];

if (vertexIndexing) {
    for (int n = 0, m = 0, i = 0; n < vertexes.size(); m++) {
        if (i + m >= vertexes.size()) {
            break;
        }
        indices.push_back((GLushort)(i+m));
        if (m >= s) {
            m = 0;
            n++;
            i+=s/2;
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << i + m << " , ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

shader->use();

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glGenBuffers(vboS, vboID);

if (vertexIndexing) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLushort), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

int n = 0;

if (options.vertex) {
    shader->addAttribute("vertex");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[n]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pos.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &pos[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader->attribute("vertex"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader->attribute("vertex"));
    n++;
}

if (options.color) {
    shader->addAttribute("color");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[n]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &colors[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader->attribute("color"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader->attribute("color"));
    n++;
}

if (options.normal) {
    shader->addAttribute("normal");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[n]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader->attribute("normal"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader->attribute("normal"));
    n++;
}

if (options.texcoord) {
    shader->addAttribute("texcoord");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[n]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoords.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &texcoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader->attribute("texcoord"), 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader->attribute("texcoord"));
    n++;
}
glBindVertexArray(0);
shader->disable();
```

}

Here is the function draw, that draws the VAO.

```
void draw() {
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
if (vertexIndexing) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
    shader->use();
    glDrawElements(mode, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    shader->disable();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
else {
    shader->use();
    glDrawArrays(mode, 0, vertexes.size());
    shader->disable();
}
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

}

Note: I removed glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) because it isnt doing anything.

Comment: Woah, `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)`!  That brings back memories of long, long ago.  It does not belong here.

Comment: This code is a bit of a mess.  It looks like you're trying to do something very generic, where one piece of code can do everything.  It would be a better idea if you started off with something that's not generic at all, but designed to work with one specific shader program and one specific vertex format.  Think about it this way: would you rather succeed at making a simple game engine, or would you rather fail by trying to make a complex game engine?

Comment: Well, i've already done many things, i have lighting, shader support, terrain, loading 3d models, textures, windows, cameras and i think it's too late to get back. But do you know whats the problem? I've been searching but i dont find anything that helps me.

Comment: It was also working before, all perfectly, but when i added indexing, it only draw the first element. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed it. It wasn't openGL's problem.
It was with the indices generation.

NEW INDICES GENERATION:

```
for (int n = 0, m = 0, i = 0; n < vertexes.size(); m++) {
    if (i + m >= vertexes.size()) {
        break;
    }
    if (m >= s) {
        m = 0;
        n++;
        i+=s/2;
    }
    indices.push_back((GLushort)(i + m));
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I ran into a similar issue where only the first object was being rendered.  I thought I had set up all of the buffers correctly.  Turned out I had only included the six indices when I needed to have nearly four-thousand.  Your answer helped me realize the problem.